# What's the reason for keeping a base line in optocoupler?

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator, phototransistor, optoelectronics

[image]
Image Source: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf

The pin no 6 of the optocoupler IC is connected to the base of the NPN transistor. Should I keep it open? Or grounded? Does it anything to do with improving the performance of the optocoupler?

Comment: Maybe to bias in it so it turn on more readily? If you ground it, it will never turn on.

Comment: For speedier usage or managed hysteresis. You can do a lot when you have access to the base that you cannot do, without it.

Comment: Proteus simulation shows that even if the base is grounded, the transistor turns on if the LED is turned on.

Comment: @Justme, thanks. That question has my answer.

Comment: @SadatRafi I don't really believe that but I've also never used one of these before.

Comment: Simulations show faulty results in many cases. So, I will check it practical later.

Comment: @SadatRafi Simulators are simulators. I think in Proteus you can also freely use microcontrollers and LCD displays without connecting power supplies properly, so people think they can omit supplies in real life too.